# Java: How to create torrent file for multiple files or directories?

Tags: java, bittorrent

The next code is a part of jBitTorrent API for Java a bit modified by me:

            `if (!torr.saveAs.matches(""))
                info.put("name", torr.saveAs);
            else
                info.put("name", "noDirSpec");
            ArrayList files = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 0; i < torr.name.size(); i++) {
                SortedMap file = new TreeMap();
                file.put("length", (Integer) torr.length.get(i));
//                String[] path = ((String) torr.name.get(i)).split("\\");
                String[] path = ((String) torr.name.get(i)).split("/");
                File f = new File((String)(torr.name.get(i)));
                ArrayList pathList = new ArrayList(path.length);`

```
            if(f.isFile())
            {
                pathList.add(path[path.length - 1]);
            }
            else if(f.isDirectory())
            {
```

**//                    ???**
                }

This is torrent file(s) generation. So the «String[] path» is commented because of «\\» doesn't match linux slashes and generate invalid paths. Specification for multiple files is:

> For the case of the multi-file mode, the info dictionary contains the following structure:
> name: the filename of the directory in which to store all the files. This is purely advisory. (string)
> files: a list of dictionaries, one for each file. Each dictionary in this list contains the following keys:
> length: length of the file in bytes (integer)
> md5sum: (optional) a 32-character hexadecimal string corresponding to the MD5 sum of the file. This is not used by BitTorrent at all, but it is included by some programs for greater compatibility.
> path: a list containing one or more string elements that together represent the path and filename. Each element in the list corresponds to either a directory name or (in the case of the final element) the filename. For example, a the file "dir1/dir2/file.ext" would consist of three string elements: "dir1", "dir2", and "file.ext". This is encoded as a bencoded list of strings such as l4:dir14:dir28:file.exte

And for single file is:

> For the case of the single-file mode, the info dictionary contains the following structure:
> name: the filename. This is purely advisory. (string)
> length: length of the file in bytes (integer)
> md5sum: (optional) a 32-character hexadecimal string corresponding to the MD5 sum of the file. This is not used by BitTorrent at all, but it is included by some programs for greater compatibility.

So if I will use the previous code for single file here will be generated this torrent:
[image]

And torrent files contains:

> d8:announce0:10:created by18:jBittorrentAPI 1.04:infod6:lengthi1645522e4:name27:ppkBB3cker-free-20101212.7z12:piece lengthi102400e6:pieces340:(ѕн‘xІZUЙ­
> ЃКХЪйкжѕЫ››3УМ‹ЁWпЖћA‡  ѕ,т C;НлАтжѓњЧ0x‡Е  %РъEЬ™сЖ®6ЦоёSЌ1пж`.бй%»†Ґ0VЩ%“ѕђoђџ'hЃ7ЦЭjъ\!RОQ.lВЦрjяGЋХ®^zЏ
> ЎЉSЖЕ|„1D”кCРк+бћJLХmЛF`Ы"ГљSЪv$Л
> Оuњi€ЙxQee

Okay. But how I should generate torrent for directory? The problem is that in unmodified API will be generated files with full path from root. But I need something like this:
[image]
And the valid torrent file is:

> d10:created by25:Transmission/2.05 (11488)13:creation datei1302559094e8:encoding5:UTF-84:infod5:filesld6:lengthi196126e4:pathl29:1231190375_bulldozer.jar.parteed6:lengthi937518e4:pathl13:FIFA_2009-RPL35:240x320-fifa-rpl-2009(eng).jar.parteed6:lengthi802555e4:pathl13:FIFA_2009-RPL31:fifa-09-rpl_176x220_en.jar.parteed6:lengthi985098e4:pathl13:FIFA_2009-RPL36:FIFA_2009-RPL_240x320_(rus).jar.parteed6:lengthi138534e4:pathl41:GAZilaMarshrutkaUbiyca[game-torrent.info]41:GAZila_Marshrutka_Ubiyca_176x208.jar.parteed6:lengthi175851e4:pathl41:GAZilaMarshrutkaUbiyca[game-torrent.info]41:GAZila_Marshrutka_Ubiyca_240x320.jar.parteed6:lengthi827473e4:pathl33:God of War 3D (240х320).jar.parteed6:lengthi295164e4:pathl26:Men_In_Black-Alien_Assault39:Men_In_Black-Alien_Assault_176.jar.parteed6:lengthi374046e4:pathl26:Men_In_Black-Alien_Assault39:Men_In_Black-Alien_Assault_240.jar.parteee4:name53:5 отличных игр для мобильника12:piece lengthi32768e6:pieces2900:�dSI�%|Q�§I�I��oQ�CI�a1R�{ۦ��

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you use `System.getProperty("file.separator")` to create valid paths on all OS's instead of hardcoding it to the windows file separator (\)

I havent used this API, but looking at the following line..

> For the case of the multi-file mode,
>   the info dictionary contains the
>   following structure: name: the
>   filename of the directory in which to
>   store all the files.

I'm guessing you could use

```
pathList.add(path[path.length - 1]);
```

irrespective if the File object is a file or a directory.